# Laravel 4 Export Excel Multidimensional Query Result

Tags: excel, laravel

I'm trying to get PHPExcel (rather, the Laravel wrapper for it: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel ) to export my view. The query I'm running returns multiple rows as a multidimensional array (I'm using DB::select and binding that way because the query is a bit complex for Fluent)

The results look like this:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#224 (3) { 
                                ["name"]=> string(13) "Administrator" 
                                ["TotalRequest"]=> string(6) "100.00" 
                                ["TotalGiven"]=> string(6) "150.00" } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#226 (3) { 
                                ["name"]=> string(14) "Beta Alpha Psi" 
                                ["TotalRequest"]=> string(6) "363.00" 
                                ["TotalGiven"]=> string(6) "200.00" } 
[2]=> object(stdClass)#227 (3) {    
                                ["name"]=> string(30) "Student Government Association" 
                                ["TotalRequest"]=> string(7) "1225.00" 
                                ["TotalGiven"]=> string(6) "620.00" } 
}
```

The Laravel-Excel package only takes in a $data array(), so I'm confused how to convert my multi-dimensional array into my view. I can get it to work if I use the alternative

```
View::make(xxxx)->with('example', $example)
```

Am I overlooking how to pass $data as an array when I have objects involved in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a multi-dimensional `array` but an `array` of objects. If you pass the `array` to your view using something like this:

```
View::make('xxxx')->with('example', $example)
```

Then in your view you may loop it using `@foreach`, like this:

```
@foreach($example as $item)
    {{ $item->name }}
    {{ $item->TotalRequest }}
    {{ $item->TotalGiven }}
@endforeach
```

Because, the array contains multiple `stdClass` objects and the first object is (`0`):

```
{ 
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Administrator" 
    ["TotalRequest"]=> string(6) "100.00" 
    ["TotalGiven"]=> string(6) "150.00" 
}
```

So, you may also retrieve the first object from the `$example` array using something like `$example[0]` and to retrieve the second object you may use `$example[1]` and so on.

Comment: But I cannot use the ->with() function in conjunction with Laravel-Excel (it only accepts Views made like this: View::make('view.name', $data)). I need this data turned into a straight array.

Comment: It doesn't matter how do you pass the data but you also can use `View::make('view.name', array('data' => $data))`.

Comment: Yes, but "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" is the error I get when I try to foreach the data I'm passing.

Comment: Inside `@foreach` loop can you just do {{ dd($item) }} instead of `{{ $item->name }}` for testing and tell me what you get ?

Comment: That renders this, along with the rest of the html content on the page: `object(stdClass)#224 (3) { ["name"]=> string(13) "Administrator" ["TotalRequest"]=> string(6) "100.00" ["TotalGiven"]=> string(6) "150.00" }`

Comment: Then you should be able to do `{{ $item->name }}` because it's an object and has `name, TotalRequest and TotalGiven` properties in it, make sure you are doing it properly.

Comment: Try `{{ dd($item->name) }}` again and see if you get a name.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help :) Putting the query results into array('data'=>$data) was the solution.

Comment: `->with('key', 'value')` and  `->withKey('value')` support for `loadView()` was very recently added. See the github readme.

Answer (score 0):

Well I Would suggest you simply change the Fetch Mode to return an array directly using a method like the one below

```
public function getQueryResult($returnQueryAs = null)'
{
    $tablename = 'YourAwesomeTable';

    if($returnQueryAs == 'array')
    {
        DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    return DB::table($tablename)->get();
}
```

then do something like this

```
public function exportAsExcel()
{
    $filename = 'nameoffile';
    $data = $this->getQueryResult($as = 'array');

    Excel::create($filename, function($excel) use ($filename, $data) {

        // Set the title
        $excel->setTitle($filename);

        // Chain the setters
        $excel->setCreator('Damilola Ogunmoye');

        $excel->sheet('SHEETNAME', function($sheet) use ($data) {


            $sheet->fromArray($data);

        });

    })->download('xls');
}
```

This Would get an associative array as opposed to an stdClass object which you can pass directly.